# Legacy Questions: a script to restore functionality to the questions list

Tags: support, user-interface

## [Legacy Questions - Bringing back the old questions design](https://stackapps.com/questions/9293/legacy-questions-bringing-back-the-old-questions-design)

Stack Exchange recently changed the UI of the main questions page, [and it was poorly received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/674198) because it is terrible, or in the words of the legendary Shog9, ["Good lord, what a flaming trainwreck"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-site-home-pages-and-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-el/375478#comment1250866_375478). My [request to change it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375478/674198) seems to be doing well, maybe SE will listen. In the mean time, a user named [Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14251221/spectric) has put together a user script to restore some of the previous functionality.

Without the script, the new view looks like:

[image]

And turning on the script, we have:

[image]

Installing the script requires a browser app, I personally use [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

Comment: "It was poorly received because it is terrible." I couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: @screamline ["Good lord, what a flaming trainwreck"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375081/new-post-summary-designs-on-greatest-hits-now-everywhere-else-eventually/375478?noredirect=1#comment1250866_375478) -Shog9

Comment: I'm trying to decide if I prefer the [is:question search results](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=is%3aquestion) better than the new front page now, it's still not as good as the old front page but at least it has snippets of the question to show instead of wasted whitespace.

Comment: @CTWind: Why not just use the [/questions](/questions) page, instead of searching for all questions?

Comment: Oh, huh, genuinely never clicked that. Always just went to the home page. Though looking at it, the search results seem to still have less wasted whitespace.